# How to scroll down a panel in VB.NET using button without scrollbar

Tags: vb.net, scrollbar, panel, tabcontrol

I would like to know how to scroll down my `Panel` that contains a `TabControl` 
in VB.NET using a button without showing a scrollbar. I tried the following

```
Dim Location As Integer = Panel_Images.Location.Y

If Location + 20 < Panel_Images.VerticalScroll.Maximum Then

    Location += 20
    Panel_Images.VerticalScroll.Value = Location

Else

    'If scroll position is above 280 set the position to 280 (MAX)
    Location = Panel_Images.VerticalScroll.Maximum
    Panel_Images.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(0, Location)
End If
```

It only scrolls for once and doesnt work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to set the location of the Panel inside another control? If you want to scroll the control up, set it's location.Y (or its 'Top') property to minus whatever value you want, it will be clipped by its parent.

To scroll down, set the property positive.